# function notation question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

So if a function is a process that associates each $x\in X$, known as the domain of the function, a unique element $y\in Y$ known as the  the co-domain of the function.

So to outline a few things I think are correct (Please let me know if I have a wrong understanding):

- A function is usually denoted by a single letter like $f$, $g$ or $h$.
- $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ at $x$. You can say $f$ is a function of the variable $x$.

It seems as though, from the comments, that $f$ can be defined by saying what it does to a general element of its domain by stating an identity and then a domain for which it is true. for example:

- $f$ is defined by $f(x)=x+1$ for $x>0$
- or, $g(x)= x + 1$ for all $x>2$ would define $g$

  I think what I have done is write $2$ identities which means that both sides of the relation define the same function of $x$ on the domain stated.

Question 1: So $f$ is the function, $f(x)$ is the value of the function at $x$ and $x+1$  is the value of $f$ at $x$. Is it right that $f(x)$ tells you that $f$ is a function of $x $ and $x+1$ is a function of $x$. I find this hard to understand as I have just said that $x + 1$ is the value of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: $f(x)= y= x+1.$  So $f(x) = y$ is in $Y$, which is in the codomain.  $x$, as you said, comes from the domain of $X$.  So given $x=2 \in \mathbb Z$, $f(x)= y= 2+1=3 \in Y$.  Indeed, $f(x) = x+1$ is a function expressed in terms of $x$.  The only thing not specified is the set $X$. That is, $f: X\to Y$ describes a function such that for every $x \in X$, there exists a unique value $f(x)$ given by $x\mapsto x+1$. The codomain, or rather, the image of $f(x)$ will depend in part on the domain of $X$.

Comment: Your question $2$: $f$ has been implicitly defined by merely $f: X\to f[X]$, where $f[X]$ is a set, and is the image of $f(x)$, and consists of all elements $y$ such that such that $y=x+1$.

Comment: In both cases, $f(x)$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is clearly a question from someone who is trying to understand functions.

Comment: Not from me, @JohnDouma.  I take the question as trying to understand the definition of a function, and whether or not a "function" without a codomain designated explicitly, is defined.  I think it's a valid question, and it is clear that James has put some thought into expressing his question as best he can.

Comment: instead of saying f(x) is a function of x is f not a function of x

Comment: @JamesAnthony You are correct; $f$ is a function and $f(x)$ is the value of that function at $x$.

Comment: if $f(x)= x + 1$ for all $x\in X$ then while you could take X to be the domain of f all you really know is that the relation is an identity on that domain. To define f with no confusion this: $$f:X \longrightarrow Y\\ f(x) = x + 1$$ should probably be used i think